# A little confusing about model in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm newbie in this flutter.
I have watched some videos about getting data from API  and I see some of them creating a model for the data got from API.
But I don't know why they need to create it because without the model, the code is still working right .

Can somebody explain this for me @@ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Model represents a custom data object. It helps to work efficiently with custom data. Suppose you have Data of user information and you get it from API response and it looks like something bellow

```
user: {
    name: 'user name',
    age: '25',
}
```

You get a response something like this `HashMap` representation or `JSON` data. Now you can access all those user information like...

```
map['user']['name'] // this line gives you the name of user
map['user']['age']. // this line gives you the age of user
```

there is no problem with that kind of use of `JSON` data

But in `Object-Oriented Programming` its good to represent all your Custom data as a real-world `Object` (if possible) suppose you have the user information as a `HashMap` so it's better to convert your `HashMap` to actual real-world `Object` then it's going to give you a wonderful experience while you using your data through your application.

Comment: got it. thank you for your help, Saitful Islam.